# вывод такой картины в консоль через while, for, do while

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я могу с помощью циклов fow, while, do while вывести такую картину в консоль

Comment: Просто картинка? Или она как-то должна вычисляться? Вот такой код - https://ideone.com/SFCp88 - устроит?

Comment: именно вычислять должно. а ваша ссылка не грузит к сожалению(

Comment: Если вычисляться, то описали бы, как именно. Я, например, принцип вычислений не понял. И очень странно, что вы не можете загрузить ссылку - она вполне рабочая, еще раз проверил...

Comment: @Harry ideone теперь в России не работает без впн, https://www.onlinegdb.com/ как альтернатива

Comment: На ruSO учить людей, как обойти блокировку? смешно...